# I retrieved form input in three ways in codeigniter? which one is right way

Tags: codeigniter

I retrieved form input in three ways in codeigniter? I am unsure which one is correct. I have given this line

```
    $this->load->view('userview',$data);
```

Is this correct? What is the right way to input the data from the form? When should I use an array?

I also want to know if the record was added successfully. After submitting the form, which function would I have to use and where would I put it?

view folder file name **userview.php**

```
userview.php
<form name="f1" action="" method="post"/>
<table width="500" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>UserName</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

First one-created Array and stored into variable:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array();
    if($this->input->post('submit') != NULL ){
        $postData = $this->input->post();
        $data['response'] = $postData;
    }
    $this->load->view('userview',$data);
}
```

Second one: retrieved input variable within array

```
public function index()
{
    $data['response']=array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->load->view('userview',$data);           
}
```

Third one: created one method within index function

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('userview');
    $this->getvalue();         
}
public function getvalue()
{
    if($this->input->post('submit')!==null)
    {
        $data['response']=array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->load->view('viewuser',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2nd option is good.

Answer (score 1):

All are OK, Personally I use the following when I have multiple fields:

```
$UserDetails = $this->input->post(['username', 'email', 'password']);
```

This would return a key => value pair array that contains the 3 fields I need only.

In your first example, you might be returning extra fields that you don't need.
Your second example is very verbose for my taste but it's OK.
3rd example is also very verbose for my taste but it's OK.

I would use form validation instead of manually checking if the form is posted.

```
$data = [];
$form_validation = array(
        ['field' => 'username', 'label' => 'Username', 'rules' => 'trim|required'],
        ['field' => 'email', 'label' => 'Email', 'rules' => 'trim|required|email'],
        ['field' => 'password', 'label' => 'Password', 'rules' => 'trim|required'],

);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($form_validation);
if ( $this->form_validation->run() === false ) {
    // set some error messages here
}else{
    // get data here
    $data['UserDetails'] = $this->input->post(['username', 'email', 'password']);
}
// pass data to view ??
$this->load->view('view', $data)
```

Comment: I also use same :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Form Validation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html
Input Class: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html 
Form Helper: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Good luck : )